# Правильно ли решена задача на C++?

Tags: c++

Препод дал задание по побитовым операциям, всё ли я верно выполнил?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cout<<"Введите число n, которое будем преобразовывать: ";cin>>n;
    cout<<"Введите количество сдвигов k: ";cin>> k;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (n % 2 > 0) {
            n = (n >> 1) | 32768;
            continue;
        }
        n = n >> 1;
    }
  
    cout << "Результат перестановки: "<< n;
}
```

Comment: 1. Угадайте задание, которое мне дал "препод". 2. Скажите мне, правильно ли я его выполнил.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну, запустите программу и посмотрите, правильный ли результат получился, наверное?

Comment: Мда, несколько странное решение... И — каков размер `int` в вашей системе?

Comment: Я же приложил скриншоты заданий, хочу узнать, оно верное или нет, чтобы мне помогли, что-то исправили, предложили своё решение, смысл с нуля засирать?
https://i.imgur.com/Yc1IAO8.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/kyNq4af.jpg

Comment: Первая ошибка в использовании int вместо unsigned int. Это важно, потому что для знакового типа двоичное представнеие отцательных чискл не определено, и операция сдвига, как следствие, не специфицирована.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы делал так:

```
const int bits = 8*sizeof(unsigned int);
unsigned int n, k;
cin >> n >> k;
k %= bits;
n = (n >> k) | (n << (bits-k));

cout << n << endl;
```

Comment: char - может юыть не 8-битным. лучше использовать numeric_limits или CHAR_BIT.

Comment: @Chorkov Может. Но это скорее теоретически, так что мне было лень, откровенно говоря... :)